# Understanding Tkinter Tk, Frame, and Toplevel object types (from a Java Swing perspective)

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm having trouble understanding the types of different variables related to Frames and windows in Tkinter (in Python). Note that I come from the world of Java Swing (and some C# WinForms).

There are 3 main types in Tkinter that I'm aware of: `Tk`, `Frame`, and `Toplevel`. Right now, I think of the types this way:

- A `Tk` object is a window, so it's a `Frame` from Java Swing.
- A `Frame` object is where you place widgets, so it's a `Panel` from Java Swing.
- A `Toplevel` object is both a window and where you place widgets, so it's a combination of `Frame` and `Panel` from Java Swing. All popup windows must be of this type. You shouldn't make another pair of `Tk` and `Frame` instances. At the same time, the main window can't be of this type.

With Tkinter, if I want to add a widget to a window, I add it to a `Frame` or a `Toplevel`, as shown below.

```
btnCreatePopup = tk.Button(<Frame or Toplevel instance>, text='Create popup', command=createPopup)
```

However, if I want to make a popup window modal, I don't use the same 2 types as I did for the widget, as shown below.

```
<Tk or Toplevel instance>.wm_attributes('-disabled', True)
```

I guess I'm confused because `Toplevel` objects accept both window attributes and widgets, but `Tk` objects only accept window attributes and `Frame` objects only accept widgets? Is my understanding of the 3 types in the bulleted list above correct and I am thinking about the types correctly? Do any of these 3 classes share a parent class that would help me understand the concept in Tkinter? I saw `Wm` (Window Manager) is a shared parent class of `Tk` and `Toplevel`, which tells me they are both windows, but I only add widgets to 1 type of `Wm` and not the other type of `Wm`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this answer clears up some confusion, but I'm afraid it might make it more confusing. The problem in talking about this is that tkinter widgets don't really exist in a hierarchy like swing widgets do. In the underlying tk library, the hierarchy is essentially flat -- all widgets are peers of each other and none inherit from any others.

> There are 3 main types in Tkinter that I'm aware of: Tk, Frame, and Toplevel

Three seems to be a reasonable number, but I think the three types are "window" (`Tk` and `Toplevel`), "widget" (`Frame`, `Button`, `Entry`, etc), and "menu" (the `Menu` widget).

There's nothing particularly special about a `Frame` widget. You can put it inside any other widget, and you can put almost any other widget inside a frame.

> You shouldn't make another pair of Tk and Frame instances.

That is half correct. Under most circumstances you should only have a single instance of `Tk` even though more are technically possible (but with consequences that might not be obvious) However, you can create as many instances of `Frame` that you want. They are very useful for grouping widgets together when laying out your widgets inside a window.

> With Tkinter, if I want to add a widget to a window, I add it to a Frame or a Toplevel

Technically, you can add almost any widget to almost any other widget, with the exception that you can't put widgets inside a `Menu`. You could put a frame inside a scrollbar if you wanted, or a canvas inside a text widget, or a frame inside a label. Of course, a lot of that won't make much sense from the user perspective. For the most part, other widgets are placed directly inside a `Tk`, `Toplevel`, or inside a `Frame` since all three are designed to be containers for other widgets. There are other widgets designed to be containers too, such as `PanedWindow`, `LabelFrame`, and the `Notebook` widget from the ttk module.

> I guess I'm confused because Toplevel objects accept both window attributes and widgets, but Tk objects only accept window attributes and Frame objects only accept widgets?

`Tk` objects can have any other widget inside it, except for a `Toplevel` or another instance of `Tk`. It is quite normal and common to put text widgets, canvases, labels, buttons, and scrollbars directly inside a `Tk` or `Toplevel` window.

> Do any of these 3 classes share a parent class that would help me understand the concept in Tkinter?

Not really. Technically, all tkinter widget classes except `Tk` inherit from `Widget` or `BaseWidget`, but the underlying tk widgets don't inherit from anything. Those base classes mostly supply some common functionality such as the `pack`, `place`, and `grid` methods.

Comment: This did help me! Now I understand a `Tk` and a `Toplevel` are different classes that both serve similar "window" functionality and allow widgets to be placed onto them. A `Frame` is just another widget that is like a `Panel` in Java Swing and does not have to be added to a `Tk`. ..... Just to clarify, are the types in angled brackets in these 2 lines correct? `btnCreatePopup = tk.Button(<Tk, Toplevel, or any other widget (including Frame but not Menu) instance>, text='Create popup', command=createPopup)` and `<Tk or Toplevel instance>.wm_attributes('-disabled', True)`